# getText() from editText to number is not working

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to get number from editText, and I keep getting an error. what should I do?

I searched here and I found that I need to do it in a way of:
getText().toString();
and then:
Integer.parseInt(X);
but it doesn't work

the inputType of the editText in the .xml is "number"

here is my relevant code:

```
   package johnny.tip2;

   import android.app.AlertDialog;
   import android.content.DialogInterface;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.TextView;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText percent, guys, meal;
TextView textView;
String guy, houm, perc;
Button how_much;
int p, g, hm, tip, tipR, oneTip, oneTip2, addTip;
boolean flag = false;
AlertDialog.Builder builder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    percent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.percent);
    guys = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.guys);
    meal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.meal);
    how_much = (Button) findViewById(R.id.how_much);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


    how_much.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            guy = guys.getText().toString();
            g = Integer.valueOf(guy);
            houm = how_much.getText().toString();
            hm = Integer.valueOf(houm);
            perc = percent.getText().toString();
            p = Integer.valueOf(perc);

            tip = hm * p / 100;
            tipR = Math.round(tip) + 1;
            oneTip = tipR / g;
            oneTip2 = Math.round(oneTip) + 1;

            if ((oneTip2 * g) < tip){
                addTip = Math.round(tip - (oneTip2 * g)) + 1;
                oneTip2 = oneTip2 + addTip;
            }


            if (percent.getText().length() == 1) {
                if (flag = false)
                openDialog();
                flag = true;
            }
           /* else{
                textView.setText("שומע? הטיפ יצא " + tip + "מה אתם אומרים? נעגל ל " + tipR + "זה אומר שכל אחד משלם " + oneTip2 + "וגם פינקתם את המלצר, איך אני?");
            }*/
        }
    });
}

public void openDialog() {
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("יא קמצן!")
            .setMessage("נהוג לתת 10%, אל תהיה לוזר")
            .setNegativeButton("עזובתי אני מרושש וקמצן", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("יודע מה, מפנק ב10%", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                     percent.setText("10");
                     p = 10;
                }
            });
    builder.show();
}
}
```

and here is the error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{johnny.tip2/johnny.tip2.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

Comment: If the EditText has no input, there's no way there's going to be an integer value in it. You can't immediately attempt to cast the text to an integer.

Comment: the editText inputType is "number"

Comment: That doesn't mean there's a number to read. An EditText takes an input. If there's no input, there's no number.

Comment: try to put .getText.toInt();

Comment: I don't what do I need to do then. when the app is running I want it to make some calculation with the input of the editText.

Comment: `""` is **not** a number. It's **not** equivalent to **0**.

Comment: correct. there is no number at all

Answer (score 0):

use this code in your edittext on .xml file

```
android:inputType="number"
```

and use this code in .java file

```
String perc = "2158";
int p = Integer.valueOf(perc);
```

if this code worked on your codes, Perhaps the number you receive from edittext is not as int is.

please try this code .

```
String perc = percent.getText().toString();
long p = Long.valueOf(perc);
```

"**long**" in Java is the number variable

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

Comment: also - I know the input from the EditText is number because when the app is running I insert a number.

Comment: my telegram : @alimhz79

Comment: I have no private.